# Why is my javascript file creating a file in one location but trying to read it from another?

Tags: javascript, relative-path, createfile

I created a variable to hold a relative path because I cannot have a direct path since this will be installed on different PCs.

```
var mainUrlCONST = "../../annotations/annotate.xml";
```

When the initial page of the program loads, it checks to see if the file exists. 
If it does not, it creates it.

Now here-in lies the problem, it reads from exactly where I want it to, but if it does not 
see the file there, it creates it somewhere else on the PC instead of the location I specified.

This checks for the file:

```
function initializeAnnotationFile()
{
    try
    {
        var connection = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        connection.open("GET", mainUrlCONST, false);
        connection.send();

        if ( connection.readyState == 4 )
        {
        response = connection.responseText;
        }

        xml = response; 
        mainExists = true;
    }
        catch(e)
    {
        mainExists = false; 
    }
}
```

This creates the file if it does not exist:

```
function createAnnotationFile()
{
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile(mainUrlCONST, true);

    s.WriteLine( "<list>" );
    s.WriteLine( "  <section title='Annotations'>" );
    s.WriteLine( "  </section>" );
    s.WriteLine( "</list>" );
}
```

Here is the direct path that works, if it will help any.

```
var mainUrlCONST = "G:/folder/annotations/annotate.xml";
```

Comment: Your question is missing essential information: 1. What environment is this running in? 2. What does your code looking for the file look like? 3. What does your code writing to the file look like? 4. Where does the file end up? 5. Where did you *expect* it to end up? 6. Why did you expect that?

Comment: You're not showing us any code. How do you expect us to help you when you don't show us what you're doing?

Comment: What does the code where you write the file look like? What about reading the file? It's not just about the path, it's how you use the path. Also, using `..` in pathnames for a script designed portable between machines seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexWayne he didn't say that it'd be portable, just that it'd be installed on several machines.

Comment: Consider using localStorage for the storage if files are proving unreliable.

Comment: @techfoobar This seems to be very IE-oriented code, `localStorage` is not available in local apps in IE.

Comment: @Teemu - Ahh, i didn't notice the ActiveX part.

Comment: @xRuhRohx: It's great you've added the code, but a number of the questions from my initial comment remain unanswered.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When finished, runs in IE only, will be packaged as an hta when complete. I am currently doing a file search to see where it is created and will let you know when that is finished.

Comment: It might not be creating the file anywhere. I've been searching all directories. If I do var mainUrlCONST = "annotate.xml" it creates the file on the desktop.  But if I do var mainUrlCONST = "annotations/annotate.xml"  it does not create the folder or the xml file.

Comment: @xRuhRohx The saving folder must exist, `CreateTextFile()` doesn't create the folder, only the file.

Comment: In the location that I am trying to save to, the folder does exist.  I just don't understand how "../../annotations/annotate.xml" is being read by the js, but when creating the file, it does not use/see "../../annotations/annotate.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been problems with `FSO` and relative paths. All documentation says, that paths can be either absolute or relative, but personally I never have got relative paths to work.

I'm using an installation folder -based addressing system in my local apps. A simplified version is something like this:

```
function getInstallBase() {
    var defInstal = 'Application_installation_folder_name',
        selfPath = window.location.pathname.replace(/\\/g,'/');
    if (selfPath.charAt(0) === '/') { // *
        selfPath = selfPath.substring(1, selfPath.length);
    }
    selfPath = selfPath.split(defInstal);
    return selfPath[0] + defInstal + '/';   
}
var defRoot = getInstallBase();
```

`*` = IE returns /G:/... when HTA returns G:/...

`defRoot` now contains an absolute path to the installation folder, no matter where it is saved.

Put this code to a JS-file in the installation folder of your application. Where ever you need a path, provide it based on `defRoot` i.e. counted from the installation folder. In your case (assuming `folder` is the installation folder) you can use it like this:

```
var s = fso.CreateTextFile(defRoot + 'annotations/annotate.xml', true);
```

I've used this technique for portable apps, and it works like a charm. You can make executable copies to memory sticks, CDs, DVDs, where ever you want, without need to touch the code at all.

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as an answer because I have no doubt that this will work, but since the app is currently running as a website and has not been packaged and installed, there is no set install path.

Comment: @xRuhRohx I've used this also in HTAs run by intranet server without problems. Maybe you need to set `defRoot` literally for testing purposes, when on server, finally HTAs are executed in client's machine.

Comment: When it checks for the file, it checks in the correct place, but when it writes, it wants to write to the desktop.  I assume because it is running in IE and not yet packaged as an app and installed.

Comment: @xRuhRohx Maybe you're right with that assume. Anyway, if you're developing a desktop application, would it be natural to do it also in the desktop environment? HTAs run fluently locally too, without need of any packaging.